# How can the traditional \epsilon be written in revtex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, greek, revtex, alphabet

RevTeX has chosen to use the `\varepsilon` symbol for both the `\epsilon` and the `\varepsilon`: [http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/teaching/phys660/PDF/revtex4.pdf](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Ebnikolic/teaching/phys660/PDF/revtex4.pdf) (p. 25).

[image]

Is there a way to re-introduce the normal `\epsilon`?

Comment: What you call the ‘normal’ epsilon is the *lunate epsilon*, which looks  ,like the $\in$ symbol.  The normal epsilon, for any linguist, is precisely `ε`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has nothing to do with the `revtex4` class, and

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\begin{document}
$\epsilon\varepsilon\rho\varrho$
\end{document}
```

yields the expected result:
[image]

The manual has been typed with a Times font; my guess is `mathptmx`. If you look at the corresponding font table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
% contains the following declaration:
% \DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{ztmcm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\xfonttable{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\end{document}
```

[image]

you see that `\epsilon` (slot 15) and `\varepsilon` (slot 34) look in fact the same. Ditto for `\rho` and `\varrho`.

Unrelated: `revtex4` is almost 20 years old, and is listed in CTAN under "obsolete". `revtex4-2` came out last year. For new papers, it might be a good idea to switch `:-)`